# passing parameter not working in shell

Tags: hive

I have written the below shell script.
This is not working.

Not recognizng the parameter `YRMTH_1`.

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:89 Failed to recognize predicate 'as'.
>   Failed rule: 'identifier' in table or column identifier

```
YRMTH=$(hive -e "select cast(concat(substr(cast(add_months(current_date, -1) as string),1,4),substr(cast(add_months(current_date, -1) as string),6,2)) as int);")

echo $YRMTH

YRMTH_1=$YRMTH

hive -e "SELECT cust_name as cust_name_${hiveconf:YRMTH_1} from xmb_db.customer where ym=CAST(${hiveconf:YRMTH_1} as INT);" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' >/tmp/data.csv
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using -e "script", shell will substitutes all $ variables.

So, the solution is to use shell variable directly without hiveconf:

`hive -e "SELECT cust_name from xmb_db.customer where ym=CAST('$YRMTH_1' as INT);"`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance.Not throwing any error. But  not fetching any data even data is existed in the table. And also not working for column names.Please help me.

Comment: check what `select CAST('${hiveconf:YRMTH_1}' as INT);` returns.

Comment: Hi , It's giving NULL.

Comment: @ then YRMTH_1 variable passed incorrectly or undefined in shell

Comment: Could you please help  me how to pass it correctly.

Comment: hive -hiveconf YRMTH_1="$YRMTH_1"    this should work. Print it from shell script also. `echo "$YRMTH_1"`

Comment: Hi

I have tried this.But still not fetching data.

YRMTH=$(hive -e "select cast(concat(substr(cast(add_months(current_date, -1) as string),1,4),substr(cast(add_months(current_date, -1) as string),6,2)) as int);")

echo $YRMTH

YRMTH_1="$YRMTH"

echo "YRMTH_1 $YRMTH_1" -- this is printing 201710

hive -hiveconf YRMTH_1="$YRMTH_1" -e "SELECT cust_name from xmb_db.customer where ym=CAST('${hiveconf:YRMTH_1}' as INT);" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' >/tmp/data.csv

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Rock Forgot about one important thing... This works good if you are using Hive -f script.hql. for passing variables to scripts. If you are using -e "script", shell probably substitutes all $ variables.

Comment: So, the solution is to use shell variable directly without hiveconf:  -e "SELECT cust_name from xmb_db.customer where ym=CAST('$YRMTH_1' as INT);" Try this

Comment: @Rock Updated my answer. please vote or accept if you are satisfyed